# HQL to accept wildcard characters and display the matching records

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

My requirement is to accept a wild card in the textbox and show the matching records.
Currently i'm working on a maintenance project and was not sure how to modify the existing code written in hibernate(HQL) to accept wildcard characters in the query and display the matching records.
Below is the wildcard characters condition:
% = 0 to many characters
_ = 1 character

In normal SQL query i know that we use like to accept wild card chacters. Please see the sample below.

```
select * from emp where empname like '%_%';
```

Please suggest how to do it when i used hibernate(HQL).

Below is my sample code:

```
public ActionForward performSearch(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        MySearchForm searchForm = (MySearchForm) form;
        ActionMessages messages = new ActionMessages();
        searchForm.getSearchCriteria().setDoSearch(messages.isEmpty());

        if (!messages.isEmpty()) {
            addErrors(request, messages);
        }

        loadFormData(searchForm, request);

        return mapping.findForward("success");
    }
```

Comment: What does "% = 0 to many characters _ = 1 character" exactly means?

Comment: @alacambra check the definition of _SQL wildcards_, `%` is the equivalent to `.*` (in a regular expression) and `_` is `.?`

Comment: To OP: You are talking about HQL - but there is _nothing_ in your snippet that has to do with Hibernate or HQL. You should post the excerpt that creates the query.